# Legendre's Chi- Function

Tags: special-functions

I want to get the numerical value(twenty at thirty decimals) of $$\operatorname\chi_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$$
 Thanks you very much.

Comment: I don't know what the Legendre chi-function is. I also don't know what "twenty at thirty" means. I also don't see any motivation for the question, any reason to think it's worth anyone's time and effort.

Comment: Are you still there?

Comment: $$\operatorname\chi_{2}({x})=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{2n+1}}{({2n+1})^2}}$$
Is Legendre's Chi-function

 $$\operatorname\chi_{2}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=0,7559...$$

Comment: Sorry, n=0 not n=1

Comment: OK, so it's sort of like the dilogarithm function. Maybe there's some literature on calculating dilogarithms that would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Legendre chi function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_chi_function) is defined as the following

$$\chi_\nu(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)^\nu}.$$

By using the Dirichlet series of the [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) we can deduce the following identity

$$\chi_\nu(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\operatorname{Li}_\nu(z) - \operatorname{Li}_\nu(-z)\right].$$

Because you need a numerical value of the chi function at order $2$, the identity above turn into a [dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) identity.

$$\chi_2(z) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\operatorname{Li}_2(z) - \operatorname{Li}_2(-z)\right].$$

At $z=\sqrt{2}/2$ we could reduce it into the form

$$\chi_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) = \chi_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{1}{2}\left[\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right) - \operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\right] = \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)-\frac{\pi^2}{48}+\frac{\ln^2 2}{8}.$$

The first $500$ digits of $\chi_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$ are the following.

$0.75609964689557998357406116157876985057285511798172214985738130157864573099\\
66741725489537316251012365900537093263317726910769815441504106893716207216441\\
09451098075219623435380238129498706729232480051698906278774001597288338615606\\
09852481717932468084405924871137380393707224388991221330477236231438246612477\\
77147546089451586432184926119404048907999162303125077730144258390374720834726\\
52427894740049923850286746477964962527589567518516877950301895647704933931095\\
84164619205084063565822266178875549517875$

Read more at [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F2%29*PolyLog%5B2%2C%20%281%2F2%29*Sqrt%5B2%5D%5D%20-%20%281%2F2%29*PolyLog%5B2%2C%20-%28%281%2F2%29*Sqrt%5B2%5D%29%5D).